# Using WHERE clause with multiple left join in php

Tags: php, mysql

I successfully did a `LEFT JOIN` using **PHP**, however, I am having a little difficulty adding a `WHERE` clause to enable me select unique record from all existing details in all the tables where a match is found.

This is my code :

```
  <?php
$sql = "SELECT staff.*, staff_bio.bio_id, staff_cert.*, staff_edu.*, staff_pos.*, staff_res.*\n"
    . " FROM staff staff\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN staff_bio \n"
    . " ON staff.nuc_id = staff_bio.bio_id\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN staff_cert\n"
    . " ON staff.nuc_id = staff_cert.pro_id\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN staff_edu\n"
    . " ON staff.nuc_id = staff_edu.edu_id\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN staff_pos\n"
    . " ON staff.nuc_id = staff_pos.rank_id\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN staff_res\n"
    . " ON staff.nuc_id = staff_res.res_id\n"
    . "WHERE staff.nuc_id = $userRow['staff_no'] ";//this is where i'm having issues
?>
```

My final output should be something like :

```
<?php echo $userRow['sch_name']; ?>
<?php echo $userRow['fac_name']; ?>
<?php echo $userRow['dep_name']; ?>
```

All coming from different tables. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all don't put the raw input of the user in the query since its insecure.The second thing is do you actually need just the LEFT JOIN do you know how it works?And a suggestion from me is that you put your whole database schema and that you explain what you want.Somebody will show how it can be done in a whole different way.....than just to put a n number of left joins, and bind the params to it since its the most secure way of doing it.Also I'm concerned of how your php code looks like :| But it's up to you what your initial goal?To make it work or to learn from this?

Comment: i'm actually creating a college accredidation app. so i have different tables for staff. tbls consist of biodata, academic records, professional qualifications and a few other tables. why i choose a left join is to enable the staff view his complete profile from all the tables when logged in. PS: i just started learning PHP so i'm not much of an expert

Comment: I think that you don't understand the left join.Update your answer please

Comment: ok.. i believe LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the left (parent) table, even if there are no matches in the right (child) table. so if that is the case, when a user logs in and complete his/her form, he/she should be able to view information entered and possibly edit

Comment: You lost the point there...Show your table structure and explain your question in detail.I'm just sick of thise poor answers on stack.....

Comment: i wish i could show you a sreenshot, but there's no place to add images here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
. " WHERE staff.nuc_id = ".$userRow['staff_no'] ;//this is where i'm having issues
```

Why do you need to concatenate query, it can be written as if you want formatting :

```
<?php 

    $sql = "SELECT staff.*, staff_bio.bio_id, staff_cert.*, staff_edu.*, staff_pos.*, staff_res.*
         FROM staff staff
        LEFT JOIN staff_bio 
         ON staff.nuc_id = staff_bio.bio_id
        LEFT JOIN staff_cert
         ON staff.nuc_id = staff_cert.pro_id
        LEFT JOIN staff_edu
         ON staff.nuc_id = staff_edu.edu_id
        LEFT JOIN staff_pos
         ON staff.nuc_id = staff_pos.rank_id
        LEFT JOIN staff_res
         ON staff.nuc_id = staff_res.res_id
        WHERE staff.nuc_id = ".$userRow['staff_no'];//this is where i'm having issues

     ?>
```

Comment: If you mean variable in quotes, i think that's right if there double quotes

Comment: well, it was giving some parsing error so I changed to this for quick solution

Comment: 'WHERE staff.nuc_id = ".$userRow['staff_no'];' seriously?

Comment: @Arslan.H you should read the above comment. If you paste code snippet to any online php syntax checker, it will show parsing error. I have just tried to resolve that error quickly nothing else

Comment: It's not about the error its about how poor you have continue to write the rest of the question.At least if you are answering explain it the proper way.....

Comment: thank you eveyone for your contribution. i'm stil learning bit by bit. hopefully i'l get better soon.